# Split large xsd into one file per type

Tags: xsd

Is ther a way to split a large XSD file with multiple type definitions into one file per type?

Answer (score 2):

- Use `xs:include`.
- If you want to automitize the process, consider using XSLT. XML Schema is XML after all.